# Received error message making a webpage with Anvil: "AttributeError: 'ColumnPanel' object has no attribute 'add_compontent' "

Tags: python, html, anvil

I keep getting this error when working with Anvil. I'm trying to make it so that the home page content is inside the column panel (which is functioning like a nav bar).

```
AttributeError: 'ColumnPanel' object has no attribute 'add_compontent'
at Base, line 12
```

Here is the code:

```py
from ..Home import Home

class Base(BaseTemplate):
  def __init__(self, **properties):
    # Set Form properties and Data Bindings.
    self.init_components(**properties)
    self.content_panel.add_compontent(Home())
```

I was expecting the nav bar (column panel page) and the home page to be displayed together. The "nav" would function as a base page and clicking on each button/link would change the page content without having to essentially copy and paste the nav bar on every page.